# Swift Module map header path

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to import a C module into a Swift target based on [this blog post](http://nsomar.com/project-and-private-headers-in-a-swift-and-objective-c-framework/), however I'm having a hard time creating the `.modulemap` file.

My folder structure is:

```
include/header.h
module.modulemap
```

My module.modulemap looks like this:

```
framework module Module {
    umbrella header "include/header.h"
}
```

However, when I try to compile the project, it can't find the umbrella header. The only way it works is if it I put an absolute path, but that won't work for obvious reasons.

---

Where exactly is the base path that I'm supposed to have my include relative to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first workaround, I decided to stop f**king around with the path in the `.modulemap` file, moved it right next to the header file and changed the `spec.module_map` in `.podspec` to point a folder deeper.